# Real time audio processing in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript, web-audio-api, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I want to do real time audio processing in ClojureScript.

The MDN documentation points me to the `AudioWorkletProcessor` Class, but from what I googled, there is no obvious way to inherit from a JavaScript Class in ClojureScript. Am I missing something?

There is also the `ScriptProcessorNode`, but it is deprecated and I can not picture how to use it in ClojureScript. An example would really be helpful.

Last but not least, if somebody has another way to do real time audio processing, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with something similar recently, but using an AnalyserNode. 
Maybe this helps you get started:

```
(require '[promesa.core :as p])
(defn initialize-audio []
  (let [ctx (js/window.AudioContext.)
        analyser (.createAnalyser ctx)]
    (-> (.getUserMedia (.-mediaDevices js/navigator) (clj->js {:audio true}))
        (p/chain
         (fn[stream]
            (.createMediaStreamSource ctx stream))
         (fn[mss]
            (.connect mss analyser))))))
```

You probably want to look at this, too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode